# Unable to open 'util.pxd': File not found (file:///c:/users/wojciech/desktop/python_labs/pandas/src/util.pxd)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem when I open a xlsx file in pandas. 
I try to concatenate columns as follows:

```
path='testdata.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(path, decimal=',')
df=df.dropna(how='any',axis=0,inplace=False)
(df)
print(df.dtypes)
df['code'].astype(object).astype(int)
df['test']='test'
df['test3']=df['test']+df['name']
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Unable to open 'util.pxd': File not found (file:///c:/users/wojciech/desktop/python_labs/pandas/src/util.pxd)
```

When I open .xls file, there's no problem.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you want to achieve. Are you saying that the file is not being written?